# Getting real time list of agent states from amazon connect in .NET Core SDK

Tags: .net, .net-core, amazon-connect, aws-sdk-net

Is there a way to get the current state as well as real time state change for all agents in an Amazon connect instance through Amazon connect sdk for .NET?

I have tried different metrics as per the documentation that I could find but I can't find the one that returns all agents.

I'm trying to achieve something like below.

Method #1: returns list of agents and their states like

```
"Agent 1" : "Available" 
"Agent 2" : "On Call"
"Agent 3" : "ACW"
```

Method #2: a realtime API to subscribe which would return the same list but when the state is changed meaning :

```
EventType == "STATE_CHANGE" || EventType == "LOGIN" || EventType == "LOGOUT"
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

EDIT :
I have userd ListUsersAsync which correctly returns all agents from my amazon connect isntance. Now I'm using GetCUrrentUserDataAsync call to retrieve agent status but this API always returns zero records. I have tried this with user.Id/user.Arn from UserSummaryList as well as hard-coding a Queue ARN but still no results.

```
var currentUserDataResponse = await _connectClient.GetCurrentUserDataAsync(new GetCurrentUserDataRequest
    {
     InstanceId = "myinstanceid",
     Filters = new UserDataFilters{
    Agents = new List<string> { user.Arn }}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods on how you can approach this, which align nicely with the methods you provided in the question.

**Method 1:** Grab all users using the [ListUsers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html) API call and then iterate on them using [GetCurrentUserData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_GetCurrentUserData.html) to obtain the status of each user. This will require a few API calls, and you'd potentially need to throttle your calls to not breach the Amazon Connect call rate limit.

**Method 2:** First enable [agent event streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/agent-event-streams-enable.html). Then each of your subscribers would subscribe to the Kinesis stream and listen to state change events.

Comment: Thanks @gamliela , Can you share a bit more detail on how to subscribe to amazon events? also I have read The Amazon Connect Streams API is primarily a JavaScript library designed to be used in the client-side (front-end) applications. 
Is it possible to just have a service that would handle everything without going to JavaScript?

Comment: I have tried GetCurrentUserData but it always returns zero count. im currently logged in with an agent and the ListUsers API returns that agent as well along with other agents but GetCurrentUserData always returns zero can you let me know what am i doing wrong?
var currentUserDataResponse = await _connectClient.GetCurrentUserDataAsync(new GetCurrentUserDataRequest
{
    InstanceId = "myinstanceid",
    Filters = new UserDataFilters
    {
        Agents = new List<string> { user.Arn }
    }
});

Comment: You can read about subscribing to Amazon Connect events here, and in particular about agent events: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/connect-integrate-kinesis . All code should run in a server in language of your choice; There is absolutely no need to go to Amazon Connect Streams API nor Javascript. Regarding your other question, make sure you’re passing agent ID in the filter (rather than ARN) and check for pagination in response (“next” attribute).